# I have 4 edittext in 3 of them i give values,and in 4th edittext i have to display the sum of all 3 edittext values

Tags: android

I have 4 edittext among 3 of them i give values,and in 4th edittext i have to display the sum of all 3 edittext values simultaneously without any button click

If any one knows it means please help

Here is my code:

```
EditText val1= (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
EditText val2= (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText2);
EditText val3= (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText3);
EditText sum = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText4);
```

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: start reading just a few lines of documentation before asking this kind of questions.

Comment: EditText val1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  EditText val2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
  EditText val3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
  EditText sum=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
  sum.setText(Integer.parseInt(val1.getText().toString())+
                Integer.parseInt(val2.getText().toString())+
                        Integer.parseInt(val3.getText().toString()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this

**Get values from all 3 edit boxes, convert them into integer**

```
    int i = Integer.parseInt(val1.getText().toString());
    int j = Integer.parseInt(val2.getText().toString());
    int k = Integer.parseInt(val3.getText().toString());
    int sumofAll = i + j + k;
```

**Now show the sum in EditText 4**

```
sum.setText(sumofAll);
```

assuming your above 3 EditTexts take input as Integet Variable only

Answer (score 0):

```
sum.setText(Integer.parseInt(val1.getText().toString())+
               Integer.parseInt(val2.getText().toString())+
                       Integer.parseInt(val3.getText().toString()));
```

//note: the above code assumes that u have set the val1,val2 and val3 editTexts to recieve integer values.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.. Please use the code below:

Onclick of 4th `EditText`, implement it in following way:

```
  <EditText4>.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{
     EditText4.setText(Integer.parseInt(val1.getText().toString())+
           Integer.parseInt(val2.getText().toString())+
                   Integer.parseInt(val3.getText().toString()));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It will help you..
Apply this..in your code 
`TextView ansField;
if(field1!="" && field2!="" && field3!="")
{
ansField=Integer.parseInt(field1.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(field2.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(field3.getText().toString());`